# How to use rtweet on rstudio.cloud?

Tags: r, rstudio, rtweet

I want to authenticate with Twitter (Rtweet package) via rstudio.cloud. The problem is that the authentication opens a new page each time where I am supposed to authorise via Twitter. When I am redirected back from there, I end up in nirvana.

```
library (rtweet)
> search_users("#ICForumCH", n = 10)
Requesting token on behalf of user...
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
```

-> Twitter authentication Page ->

```
Hmmm… can't reach this page
127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
```

I found [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-rtweet-in-rstudio-cloud/94209) solution from community.rstudio.com but cannot seem to make it work.

Oh, and please don't tell me I need a desktop version. I will never get the necessary permissions at my workplace.

Comment: Someone said to create a oauth on the desktop and copy it to the server but I don't get how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If You have The twitter account logged in your default browser this may work for you.

Run this code first,

```
library(rtweet)
auth_setup_default()
# Using default authentication available.
# Reading auth from 'C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming/R/config/R/rtweet/default.rds'
```

You can take **default.rds** file and upload it to your **RStudio.cloud** folder.

Just use

```
auth_as("foldername/default.rds")
```

before post a tweet.